# Can we tonsure remotely and send hair to Tirupati?

Tags: prayer, tirupati

Can we tonsure the head in Bangalore and offer (send)  the hair in prayer to Tirupathi if we are unable to visit Tirupathi immediately ? Where to contact in Bangalore ?

Comment: If any vow is taken by mentioning name of Triumala, then it's a strict no. It must be offered only at Venkatachalam in that case. Other wise, if out of devotion one wants to offer, you can definitely visit a Balaji temple in Bangalore and do tonture, since the same devata resides in Tirumala and same is at local temple. (But this doesn't works for vows given to devata, it must be fulfilled at the place mentioned and at the time mentioned)